# Error: time data "b'YYYY/MM/DD" does not match format '%Y/%m/%d' but it does

Tags: python, string, datetime, type-conversion

I'm trying to parse dates from a textfile, but executing the scripts throws incorrect data format, when the format is correct.

The file is a .txt file with the following structure

2018/02/15 05:00:13 - somestring - anotherstring

2018/02/15 05:00:14 - somestring - anotherstring

2018/02/15 05:00:15 - somestring - anotherstring

... etc

The script gets the file divided in lines, and each line is divided on fields, of which one field is a date and time. I divided the date and the time in two separate fields, the time gets converted ok so the problem is in the date.

This is what I get on execution:

ValueError: time data "b'2018/02/15" does not match format '%Y/%m/%d'

I noticed it prints the string with a "b" in front of it, which if I'm not mistaken it means it's a byte literal. I've tried using "decode("utf-8")" on it, but it throw's exception as "string" has no method decode.

```
#the file is in one long string as I get it from a 'cat' bash command via ssh
file = str(stdout.read()) #reads the cat into a long string
strings = file.split("\\n") #splits the string into lines
for string in strings:
    fields = string.split(" - ")
    if len(fields) >= 3:
        #dates.append(datetime.strptime(campos[0],"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")) #Wrong format
        datentime = fields[0].split()
        dates.append(datetime.strptime(datentime[0],"%Y/%m/%d")) #Wrong format
        print(datentime[1])
        dates.append(datetime.strptime(datentime[1],"%H:%M:%S")) #WORKS
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out why that is happening to you with the code you gave so I can't offer a fix for that but I tried testing on it and this worked for me:

```
datetime.strptime(str(datentime[0])[2,:-1], "%Y/%m/%d")
```

It removes the B and ' from the string, if you still have problems with that, please post how you got that string, maybe there was some error on the way.

Comment: added some more info, the thing is the 'b' isn't actually there, python puts it there when printing the exception but doing print(datentime) wont print the b'

Answer (score 0):

use try and except:

```
import datetime

def convertDate(d):
    strptime = datetime.datetime.strptime
    try:
        return strptime(d, "%Y/%m/%d")
    except TypeError:
        return strptime(d.decode("utf-8"), "%Y/%m/%d")

print(convertDate(b'2018/02/15'))
print(convertDate('2018/02/15'))
```

Comment: Implemented the conversion method, still get the same error :(

Comment: is it TypeError?